# Using puppet to install postgres without puppet-postgres

Tags: postgresql, puppet

I am trying to install postgresql, set up a database and a user, but I am stuck at the setting up a database and use part. What I have so far is:

```
# Install postgres
class postgres::install {

  package { [
    'postgresql',
    'postgresql-contrib',
  ]:
  ensure => "installed",
  }
}
```

But now how do I use this to create a user, database and grant all permissions on that database to that user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a couple of ways, but the easiest way to do it repeatedly is with a define that calls a couple of execs:

```
Exec {
  path => [
    '/usr/local/sbin',
    '/usr/local/bin',
    '/usr/bin',
    '/usr/sbin',
    '/bin',
    '/sbin',
  ]
}
define postgres::db_setup (
  $dbname,
){
  exec { "configure_db_${dbname}":
    command => "pg command here using ${dbname}; touch success.txt"
    creates => "db_${dbname}_success.txt"
  }
}
define postgres::user_setup (
  $dbuser,
  $dbpassword,
  $dbname,
){      
  exec { "configure_user_${dbuser}_on_${dbname}":
    command => "pg command here using ${dbuser} on ${dbname} identified by ${dbpassword}; touch usersuccess.txt"
    creates => "user_${dbuser}_success.txt"
  }
```

Then when you call the defines:

```
postgres::db_setup { 'this_new_db':
  dbname => 'mynewdbname'
}

postgres::db_user { 'this_new_db_user_on_dbname':
  dbuser     => 'mynewdbuser',
  dbpassword => 'blahblah',
  dbname     => 'mynewdbname',
  require    => Postgres::Db_setup['this_new_db'],
}
```

This is a very dirty way to accomplish what you want by using dummy files to register when an exec has been completed. In my MySQL environment I use execs on scripts created with erb templates to allow more refined error checking.

Comment: so whats the clean way of doing this then?

Comment: @KyleAdams The clean way is to use a module that already exists, and in this specific case to implement a native provider in ruby.

Comment: I've updated the 'creates' statements to allow the defines to work with different resource declarations. If the filename is the same across the defines then only the first one will apply.